# linker command failed when building plugin

Tags: go, plugins

When I try to build a golang plugin on macOS Catalina using go 1.13.4, the build process breaks with the following error:

```
$ make buildPlugin
env GOOS=linux go build -buildmode=plugin -o bin/common common/*.go
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.4/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
ld: unknown option: -z
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make: *** [buildPlugin] Error 2
✘ $ go tool cgo -V
cgo version go1.13.4
```

Removing `env GOOS=linux` helps but it is not a solution. Any ideas about the reason for this problem?

Comment: Seems cross-compilation may not work for plugins: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/b6h8qq/is_anyone_actually_using_go_plugins/ejkxd2k/

Comment: The workaround (or better, the right way to do it) was to build and use a simplified image (only for golang 1.13) created based on this project: https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images